How can I create a box where I can simulate different screen sizes with Tailwind CSS and Next JS
I am working on creating a website builder, and I want to be able to see what the page would look like on a phone, without having to always open the web inspector and changing the width of it. I looked it up, and I couldn't find anything that worked. I want to be able to switch from desktop to tablet to phone size screens in a div (not the whole screen). I would appreciate any advice (ideas) you may have.

There are a few things you can try depending on what you want to do.
Id suggest either setting the dementions of your html:
html { width: 500px; height: 500px;}

Or putting the webpage in an iframe with a certain size. you can set the dementions of the iframe like this:
<iframe src="/yourWebPage" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

